# using split to get rid of regexp from an Arraylist

Tags: java, regex, split

I am trying to create a spell checker, but before I can do so I must read in two separate files. The first (the dictionary), I did file.  The second is a novel for which I must spell check. Problem is, I need to remove all special characters that are not letters (regexp?) from the novel. I am trying to use the string.split, but am having no luck. I am testing this one a small section of the novel, test2.

This is the section of code I have...

```
public static void readFileBook() {
    File f = new File("test2.txt");
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
        int i = 0;
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String oliver = input.next();
            list2.add(oliver);
            String[] oliverArray = oliver.split("[.#]");
            System.out.println(list2.get(i));
            i++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) { //opening failed
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}`enter code here`
```

I started small with the '.' and '#' symbols. The System.out is just to check if things are working (they aren't), but output still has symbols.

I know there is probably a more elegant way of doing this, but the instructor a specific thing in find.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Tip: Make your question explicit, clear, and one sentence. Edit it into your question. (I don't know much about regex so I can't help you, but this will make your question easier for other people to help you).

Answer (score 0):

so in you code

```
String oliver = input.next();
list2.add(oliver);
String[] oliverArray = oliver.split("[.#]");
System.out.println(list2.get(i));
```

you are (line by line)

reading input into String oliver

adding oliver to a list

splitting oliver into oliverArray which never gets used

printing the string in the list at position `i`

**How** would you know if this is working or not?

Comment: I suppose I don't, which is actually something I was afraid of. I guess I;m not sure how to check if I am doing it correctly then.

Comment: well you are not even using oliverArray, so what does it matter if your regex is coorect or not.  Anyway, think about using String.replaceAll

Comment: It matters if my regex  is correct or not because that's what I need to accomplish.  I was afraid I wasn't printing it out correctly, but every attempt to print out the array is met with Outofbounds exceptions.